# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ruby-on-rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I tried to read jquery but it did not work.
I want to hide the download and cancel button once users click the download button, and show back button.

This is error when I run.

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

This is `show.html.erb`

```html
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="download_button"><%= t(".download") %></button>
          <%= link_to t("cancel"), certs_path, class: "btn btn-default", id: "cancel_button" %>
          <%= link_to t("back"), certs_path, class: "btn btn-default", id: "back_button", style: "display:none;" %>

....

<!-- After downloading the certificate,
   prevent the button from being pressed to prevent certs re-creation. -->
<script>
    $("#download_button").on("click", () => {
        $("#download_button").hide()
        $("#cancel_button").hide();
        $("#back_button").show();
    });
</script>
```

This is `config/webpack/environment/js`

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery',
    jQuery: 'admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery',
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

This is `app/assets/javascipts/application.js`

```js
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
```

I also tried `rails s`, and `bundle update` but it did not work.

Comment: It sounds like jQuery isn't being loaded on the HTML page?

Comment: Do I need to add this below even though I add jquery to `app/assets/javascipts/application.js`

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Is the jQuery being loaded before the client script?